# How to update Django form with files and text inputs

Tags: python, django

I have an update form in Django and the code below is working particularly in this instance:

```html
def edit_project(request, project_id):
    detail = projectDB.objects.get(pk=project_id)
    form = projectForm(request.POST or None, instance = detail)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect ('/manage')
    return render(request, 'edit_project.html', {'detail': detail, 'form':form })
```

But when I inserted `request.FILES` as well to save the updated file from the form like this:

```html
def edit_project(request, project_id):
    detail = projectDB.objects.get(pk=project_id)
    form = projectForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES instance = detail)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect ('/manage')
    return render(request, 'edit_project.html', {'detail': detail, 'form':form })
```

The instance seems to not working anymore, I want to update a form that contains files and text inputs from users but I don't know how to save both at the same time.

Comment: Have you mentioned "enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form tag(html)? There is "," missing after "request.FILES. Please post your "form", "model" and any error you are getting while trying to upload.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a comma is missing just before "**,** instance = detail)"

```
def edit_project(request, project_id):
    detail = projectDB.objects.get(pk=project_id)
    form = projectForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES, instance = detail)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect ('/manage')
    return render(request, 'edit_project.html', {'detail': detail, 'form':form })
```

Comment: After inserting a comma, I can no longer open the edit_project.html where the update form is. It just redirects repeatedly to my 'manage/'

Comment: It redirects repeatedly to '/manage' surely because you have to valid your form only on post.
Please, try to add : 
`if request.method == "POST":`